# Combining two XML documents in one XSLT document and matching values

Tags: php, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two XML documents with different structures (examples below) that I want to merge in the XSLT document I use for creating HTML output.

What I want to do is to create a table like this (example with cars):

```
Serialnr    Brand    Color    Year    Price    Condition
 123456     'Opel'   'Blue'   '1978'  '10000$'   'Used'
  ...        ...      ...      ...     ...      ...
```

The last two of these (Price and Condition) are to be found in the second document (foo2.xml), and the matching between these documents is the serialnr. The cars isn't ordered in the same order in the documents, and it exist more cars in foo2.xml (that won't be used) than in foo1.xml.

**foo1.xml:**

```
<cars>
    <car>
        <serialnr>123456</serialnr>
        <brand>Opel</brand>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <year>1978</year>
    </car>
    ...and so on...
```

**foo2.xml:**

```
<vehicles>
    <vehicle>
        <cell nr="2"><data nr="3">123456</data></vehicle> // <--- match on serialnr (123456)
        <cell><data nr="3">10000$</data></cell>
        <cell><data nr="3">Used</data></cell>
    ...and so on...
```

Foo1.xml is connected to the XSLT document with PHP on the server side, and foo2.xml is merged in the XSLT document (see below).

**cars.xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

    <xsl:param name="foo2" select="'foo2.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>

        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Producers</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                       ...//table, thead, tr, th...

                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//car">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="serialnr" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="brand" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="color" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="year" />
                            </td>
                          </xsl:for-each>
                          <xsl:for-each select="document($foo2)//Vehicle">
                               // I need to match the serialnr in some way to get the correct car's data here, but how?
                               <td>
                                    // Selecting Cell node 2 (price)
                                    //<xsl:value-of select="/? "/>
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                    // Selecting Cell node 3 (condition)
                                    //<xsl:value-of select="/? "/>
                               </td>
```

So, how can I do this? I really appreciate help here. Thanks a lot in advance!

#### Notes:

1. The structure of foo2.xml isn't consistent. Suddenly the child node changes from being "vehicle" to "part" (i.e. "vehicles/vehicle" to "vehicles/part").
2. In foo2.xml there are a lot of "vehicle" nodes that contains of data I'm not interested in,  so I suppost I must use some sort of if statement to test whether the desired data exists or not when looping through them?

Comment: Your listing for foo2.xml is malformed. Please correct. Could you please give a more representative listing of foo2.xml that shows the structure that you talk about in the notes. Please simplify by removing guff data in the listing. Also don't use elipses. Show us a whole and well formed listing.

Comment: Is `vehicle/vehicle` and `vehicle/part` the only two structures that contain vehicle data? Or is foo2 an arbitrarily structured document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a guess at the answers to the questions that I posted in the main comment feed, please find this XSLT 1.0 solution.

**With this document as the main input...**

```
<cars>
   <car>
        <serialnr>123456</serialnr>
        <brand>Opel</brand>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <year>1978</year>
  </car>
   <car>
        <serialnr>789</serialnr>
        <brand>Toyota</brand>
        <color>Beige</color>
        <year>2005</year>
  </car>
</cars>
```

**... and this document as a readable document resource passed in to the style-sheet with parameter name `foo2`...**

```
<vehicles>
  <vehicle>
    <cell><data>123456</data></cell>
    <cell><data>10000$</data></cell>
    <cell><data>Used</data></cell>
  </vehicle>
  <vehicle>
    <cell><data>789</data></cell>
    <cell><data>20000$</data></cell>
    <cell><data>Pre-loved</data></cell>
  </vehicle>
```

**...this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:param name="foo2" select="'foo2.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="vehicles" select="document($foo2)/vehicles/vehicle" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html lang="en">
   <head><title>Cars</title></head>
   <body>  
     <xsl:apply-templates select="cars" />
   </body>  
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cars">
  <table>
    <th>
      <td>Serialnr</td> <td>Brand</td> <td>Color</td> <td>Year</td> <td>Price</td> <td>Condition</td>
    </th>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="car" />
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="car">
  <xsl:variable name="srl" select="serialnr/text()" />
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$srl" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="brand" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="color" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="year" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$vehicles/self::*[cell/data=$srl]/cell[2]" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$vehicles/self::*[cell/data=$srl]/cell[3]" /></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...will yield this output** (a HTML5 document) ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Cars</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <th>
        <td>Serialnr</td>
        <td>Brand</td>
        <td>Color</td>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Condition</td>
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>Opel</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>1978</td>
        <td>10000$</td>
        <td>Used</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>789</td>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>Beige</td>
        <td>2005</td>
        <td>20000$</td>
        <td>Pre-loved</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Note

A solution using keys would also be possible.